# Remove [[Prototype]] : Object / From Array / DataCloneError Error Dexie indexDB Put

Tags: javascript, quasar-framework, dexie

I am trying to save an array to indexDB via Dexie and I'm getting a DataCloneError.

This is the layout of the array I've built (image below).  The only thing I can see that is not a supported type that would throw that error is the

```
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

That appears in my array.

[image]

Everything else is a string, a boolean, a number, or undefined. I've changed all array elements to just strings and it still wont save, still throws the error.

Is there a way to get rid of that prototype part of the array? I've been Googling and haven't found any answers.

I build the array with a .push as the user clicks checkboxes to add items they want just using a push:

```
this.detailArrayAllEntries.push({
  enteredDate: theDate,
  enteredTrial: theTrialNum,
  enteredElement: theElement,
  enteredLevel: theLevel,
  enteredBox: enterThisBox,
  enteredAorB: aOrBModel,
})
```

And every time the user selects a checkbox and the push runs, the array that is built includes that "prototype:Array".

I'm just using a .put to save the data to the database (newEntry is the variable that has all the information I'm saving).

```
await theDB.theTable
     .put(newEntry)
```

Here is newEntry:

```
let newEntry = {
        clubName: this.eventClub,
        dog: {
          pk_dog:  this.enteredDogsInfo.pk_dog,
          dogBday: this.enteredDogsInfo.dogBday,
          dogBreed: this.enteredDogsInfo.dogBreed,
          dogCallName: this.enteredDogsInfo.dogCallName,
        },
        editEntry: false,
        entries: this.detailArrayAllEntries, // broken
        eventBusinessName: this.eventBusinessName,
        eventID: theEventID,
        eventName: this.eventName,
        eventSecretaryEmail: this.eventSecretaryEmail,
        eventSecretaryName: this.eventSecretaryName,
        eventStartDate: this.eventStartDate,
        eventType: this.eventType,
        person: {
          p_key: this.enteredPersonInfo.pk_person,
          f_lastName: this.enteredPersonInfo.f_lastName,
          f_firstName: this.enteredPersonInfo.f_firstName,
          f_email: this.enteredPersonInfo.f_email,
        },
        totalEntryFees: this.saveEntryFeesWithProcessing,
        }
```

This is driving me crazy why it won't save, and the only thing I can really think that's not working is that Prototype, but I don't know how to build the array without it, or strip it out once it's there.

I am using Quasar... so this is Javascript.

Comment: Can we see the error message itself? You cannot get rid of the prototype chain, but that would not be stopping the dexie operation

Comment: The prototype chain is normally ignored in the structuredClone that IndexedDB uses but I'm not sure how ’detailsArrayAllEntries’ was created. In your schreenshot it's apparently a Proxy. Have you created it or retrieved it through a framework?